# MySQL SELECT. LIMIT number of values from one column

Tags: mysql

Task: From MySQL standard database "world" select all the cities with population more then a million, limiting number of countries to 10.
If I do this:

```
SELECT country.Name, city.Name, city.Population
FROM country
INNER JOIN city
  ON country.Code = city.CountryCode
WHERE city.Population >= 1000000
LIMIT 10;
```

it produces this:

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Name        | Name         | Population |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Afghanistan | Kabul        |    1780000 |
| Algeria     | Alger        |    2168000 |
| Angola      | Luanda       |    2022000 |
| Argentina   | Buenos Aires |    2982146 |
| Argentina   | La Matanza   |    1266461 |
| Argentina   | CÃ³rdoba     |    1157507 |
| Armenia     | Yerevan      |    1248700 |
| Australia   | Sydney       |    3276207 |
| Australia   | Melbourne    |    2865329 |
| Australia   | Brisbane     |    1291117 |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

Argentina, for example, is repeated 3 times. I need to limit number of countries to 10, not number of rows.
GROUP BY won't do since I need all the cities, I don't need them grouped.

The expected result would be this:

```
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------+
| Name               | Name                       | Population |
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------+
| Afghanistan        | Kabul                      |    1780000 |
| Algeria            | Alger                      |    2168000 |
| Angola             | Luanda                     |    2022000 |
| Argentina          | Buenos Aires               |    2982146 |
| Argentina          | La Matanza                 |    1266461 |
| Argentina          | CÃ³rdoba                   |    1157507 |
| Armenia            | Yerevan                    |    1248700 |
| Australia          | Sydney                     |    3276207 |
| Australia          | Melbourne                  |    2865329 |
| Australia          | Brisbane                   |    1291117 |
| Australia          | Perth                      |    1096829 |
| Azerbaijan         | Baku                       |    1787800 |
| Bangladesh         | Dhaka                      |    3612850 |
| Bangladesh         | Chittagong                 |    1392860 |
| Brazil             | SÃ£o Paulo                 |    9968485 |
| Brazil             | Rio de Janeiro             |    5598953 |
| Brazil             | Salvador                   |    2302832 |
| Brazil             | Belo Horizonte             |    2139125 |
| Brazil             | Fortaleza                  |    2097757 |
| Brazil             | BrasÃ­lia                   |    1969868 |
| Brazil             | Curitiba                   |    1584232 |
| Brazil             | Recife                     |    1378087 |
| Brazil             | Porto Alegre               |    1314032 |
| Brazil             | Manaus                     |    1255049 |
| Brazil             | BelÃ©m                     |    1186926 |
| Brazil             | Guarulhos                  |    1095874 |
| Brazil             | GoiÃ¢nia                   |    1056330 |
| United Kingdom     | London                     |    7285000 |
| United Kingdom     | Birmingham                 |    1013000 |
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------+
```

As you can see, number of countries is 10, no matter how many cities.

Of course, my database is different. I used the "world" for simplicity, generality, and availability.
In the real db I also do some filtering on "country".

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work

```
SELECT country.Name, city.Name, city.Population
FROM country
LEFT JOIN city
  ON country.Code = city.CountryCode
WHERE city.Population >= 1000000
AND city.id IN (SELECT id FROM city WHERE city.Population >= 1000000 AND country.Code = city.CountryCode LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Thanks.
1. I think it's a bit inefficient.
2. Gives this error: 
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/AN
Y/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

```
//So sorry try this query

SELECT country.Name, city.Name, city.Population
FROM country
LEFT JOIN city
  ON country.Code = city.CountryCode
WHERE city.Population >= 1000000 and country.Code IN(SELECT distinct CountryCode FROM city WHERE Population >= 1000000 LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is almost the same as the previous one. And it produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Generate temporary row level id's for each of the unique country in a sub query and select rows from it applying a where condition like `where temp_row_num is <= 10`.

**Example**:

```
select
       /*uq_country_row_num, */ 
       country_name, city_name, population
from (
  select country_name, city_name, population
    , case when @pn=(@cn:=country_name) 
           then @r:=(@r + 1) 
           else @r:=1
      end as uq_country_row_num
    , @pn:=@cn as temp_cn
  from population, 
       (select @pn:='', @cn:='', @r:=0) country_rown_nums
  -- use order by country_name if the result set is un-ordered
  order by
     country_name
) all_results
where
  uq_country_row_num <= 10
;
```

You can un comment the variable `/*uq_country_row_num, */`, if you want them as part of the output.

**Example** @ [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec9d1/3)

---

**Edit**:
From the comments:

> *You mean 10 rows per country or all records from max 10 countries?*
>
> *Exactly, "all records from max 10 countries".*

```
select
  country_id,
  country_name, city_name, population
from (
  select 
    country_name, city_name, population
    , case when @pn=(@cn:=country_name) 
           then @country_id:=@country_id 
           else @country_id:=(@country_id + 1)
      end as country_id
    , @pn:=@cn as temp_cn
  from population, 
       (select @pn:='', @cn:='', @row_num:=0, @country_id:=0) country_row_nums
  order by country_name
) all_results
where
  country_id <= 10
;
```

**Example 2** @ [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/689bf/9)

Comment: Thanks. I am not quite good at SQL, so I didn't understand all of your code. But it doesn't work. Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/689bf/1. Simply selects all the rows.

Comment: can you please explain where it failed.

Comment: I just checked. You can use `ORDER BY country_name` so that all country names are sorted first and then row numbers are allotted.

Comment: There, by the link. You see, It selects all the rows. I need maximum of 10 different countries.

Comment: @Tigran: You mean 10 rows per country or all records from max 10 countries?

Comment: I am sorry, the new query yields the same results. Number of countries is still not limited to 10: it's much more. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/689bf/7

Comment: @Tigran: Please respond to my previous comment.

Comment: Exactly, "all records from max 10 countries".

Comment: Ravinder, there is another detail I overlooked while checking your code previous time: there are 2 tables: country and city, not one. I need some data from both tables. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You can use *the way, the solution suggested*.

Comment: Thank you. Posted my own answer. Looks like it is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
SELECT city.Name, city.Population, newcountry.name
FROM city
INNER JOIN 
(select distinct Name,Code
 from country limit 10) newcountry
  ON newcountry.Code = city.CountryCode
WHERE city.Population >= 1000000;
```

Comment: Thanks, but... wrong. This query produces sets with less than 10 countries. Why? FIRST, 10 countries are selected, THEN they are filtered again by population. Not all the countries have cities with population larger than 1 million, so they get cut.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked. So I had to use the following request:

```
SELECT co.Code, co.Name, ci.Name, ci.Population
  FROM city ci
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT co.Code, co.Name
        FROM country co
          INNER JOIN city ci
          ON ci.countryCode = co.Code
        WHERE ci.Population > 1000000
        ORDER BY co.Name
        LIMIT 10
    ) co
    ON ci.countryCode = co.Code
  WHERE ci.Population > 1000000;
```

It seems rather clumsy and not efficient to me (notice the repetition of the condition), but for lack of a better way, this is the only solution.

Thanks to everyone for your answers anyway.